# Is there a way to define a range with infinite row or column number in a spreadsheet program?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

When defining a named range in a spreadsheet program, **is there a way to define a range that covers for example `A1:A[*infinity*]`**, so I will be sure that the range will always include all rows, whether new rows are added to the sheet later?

For now I use `A1:A999999` but maybe there's a better and more future proof way (I mean, who know's what'll happen to this sheet in a couple of hundred years?! ;) )

Comment: Use VBA. See [5 Different Ways to Find The Last Row or Last Column Using VBA — TheSpreadsheetGuru](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should simply be able to use A:A if you are always starting from the first row

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a table, as they can auto-expand.

Comment: It does provide an answer. Table objects do what OP wanted: infinite (to some extent) rows with non-changing reference when the amount of rows increases.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how a table addresses your question.

The range B3:C9 is a table created using "Insert Table" command. I left the default name "Table1." Cells E3 and E4 contain two versions of a formula that addresses the table by name, and a column by name. No cell references are used. If I added a new row to the bottom of the table simply by typing or copying, the definition of the table boundary would expand, and the formulas would recalculate.

[image: Illustration]

Comment: This is an interesting alternative solution!